# Java: Error while saving date value to database(Simpledataformat)

Tags: java, date, timestamp, simpledateformat

I am trying to save a date in DB but i am getting the below error. I am confused because i am sending the same format but still throwing exception:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Timestamp format must be
>   yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss[.fffffffff]

If i am trying in **SQL Developer** in the below way it works fine

```
to_date('01/01/1900', 'mm/dd/yyyy')
```

Through java i tried doing as below

First Method

```
SimpleDateFormat format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
Date myDate = format1.parse("01/01/1900 00:00:00");
```

Second Method

```
SimpleDateFormat format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Date myDate = format1.parse("01/01/1900");
```

Where am i going wrong.

**P.S : Please before marking it as duplicate and stopping people from answering question understand i have tried something and got the error.**

Comment: can you show us the part of your code that is actually trying to write to SQL

Comment: @alainlompo: row   = new STRUCT(myNewRon, getConnection(), attributes);

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject(
    … , 
    LocalDate.parse( 
        "01/01/1900" , 
        DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd/MM/uuuu" )
    )
)
```

## Details

The [Answer by Just another Java programmer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40551998/642706) is correct.

Furthermore, you should not use strings to communicate date-time values with a database. Use date-time classes.

The modern way is with java.time classes, supplanting the troublesome legacy date-time classes.

## `LocalDate`

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z );
```

You can parse directly from a string in standard ISO 8601 format.

```
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse( "2016-01-23" );
```

Or specify each part.

```
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.of( 2016, Month.JANUARY , 23 );
```

To parse other formats, use [`DateTimeFormatter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) class. Search Stack Overflow for many examples.

## Database

If your [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) complies with [JDBC 4.2](https://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=221) or later, it should be able to pass a java.time type with `PreparedStatement::setObject` and fetch with [`ResultSet::getObject`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getObject-int-java.lang.Class-).

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , localDate );
```

…or…

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , localDate , JDBCType.DATE );
```

If your driver is not so enabled, fall back to using [`java.sql.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html). This awkward class pretends to represent a date-only value (but actually has a time component set to midnight which we are supposed to ignore). To convert to/from java.time look to new methods added to the old classes.

```
java.sql.Date sqlDate = java.sql.Date.valueOf( localDate );
```

And going the other direction.

```
LocalDate localDate = sqlDate.toLocalDate();
```

Pass to [`PreparedStatement::setDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setDate-int-java.sql.Date-).

```
myPreparedStatement.setDate( … , sqlDate );
```

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to java.time.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [*ThreeTenABP*](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts ***ThreeTen-Backport*** (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

Your date pattern does not match.

Better is to use a [`PreparedStatement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) so you never will rely on string conversion.